External monitor receives no signal when going higher than 60Hz after installing NVIDIA drivers
External monitor receives no signal when going higher than 60Hz after installing NVIDIA drivers. Works fine after disabling the external monitor from settings and selecting higher refresh rate from NVIDIA X Server. But I have to repeat these steps after every boot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
